# Modifying the AJAX PHP database example

Tags: php, ajax, database, html

I would like to create something like this show here:

http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_ajax_database.asp

But instead of drop down list shown in the example, is it possible to change it to table format  like example, when I click on the Class 1 it will display the details for class 1...the details are in my database its from phpmyadmin:

Thanks in advance...help greatly appreciated

Is this correct?

```
<?php
include ('staffheader.php');
?>
<div id="head">Permit Structure</div>
<div class="contents">
<div id="class_data">
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td>Road Based</td>
<td>Proving Ground PG</td>
<td>Off Road OR</td>
<td>Towing TT</td>
</tr>
<tr id="Class_1">
<td> <a href='#' class='classlink' title='1'>Class 1</a></td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Class 2</td>
<td>CAT 2PG</td>
<td>CAT 1OR</td>
<td>CAT 2TT</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Class 3</td>
<td>CAT 3PG</td>
<td>CAT 2OR</td>
<td>CAT 3TT</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>CAT 4PG</td>
<td>CAT 3OR</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="instruction">Click on the Class or Category to view information on it</div>
</div>
<div id='detailtable'></div>
<?php
include('allfooter.php');
?>
```

loadergetclassinfo.php:

```
<?php
$class_id = empty($_POST["class_id"]) ? 1 : $_POST["class_id"];
   $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "cailing8195") or die ("Unable to connect to MySQL Server " . mysql_error()); 
if(is_resource($con))
    $db = mysql_select_db("jlr", $con) or die( "Unable to select database " . mysql_error());
$query = "SELECT PTYPE, TYPE, PREREQ, DES FROM type WHERE TYID=" . $class_id;
$res = mysql_query($query);
$arr_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
mysql_close($con);

foreach ($arr_data as $data)
$html = "<table>\n";
$html .= "<tr><th>Type ID</th><th>Permit Type</th><th>Categories</th><th>Pre-Requisisite</th><th>Description</th></tr>\n";
$html .= "<tr><td>" . $class_id . "</td><td>" . $data['PTYPE'] . "</td><td>" .    $data['TYPE'] . "</td><td>" . $data['PREREQ'] . "</td><td>" . $data['DES'] . "</td>    </tr>\n";
 $html .= "</table>\n";

echo $html;
?>
```

JQuery (in javascript.js):

```
 $(function() {
$('a.class_link').click(function() {
    var class_id = $(this).attr('title');
    $.post("loadergetclassinfo.php", {class: class_id}, function(result){
    $('#detail_table').html(result);
    });
   });
});
```

And i add this inside my header php file too:

```
  <script src="javascript.js"></script>
 <script type='text/javascript'     src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: I found some more errors - see my update below.

Comment: Change `$('#detail_table')` in jQuery code to `$('#detailtable')`

Comment: A mistake in my jQuery code: Change `$('a.class_link')` to `$('a.classlink')`

Comment: Also change the order of your script tags: The jQuery library source code should be first in the header, before your script file.

Comment: Don't add the jQuery into your php file's header - it's only needed in your HTML file (the file with the links).

Comment: it doesn't need to be in the head tag rite?

Comment: Hmm...its kinda of working but the result it return in the table is 1 for the type ID and S S S S for each other column...any idea why??

Comment: Your script declarations must be in the head tag, i.e. in staffheader.php.  The jQuery script we use can either be in an external file or in script tags in the header. By the way, I just tested this, and it works.

Comment: Actually, if you really want (not recommended) your script tags can be in the page body as well.  Anyway, I am trying to see why your returned data is not right....

Comment: Yes, I think I see the problem:  Change $data['colname'] to $arr_data['colname'] in the php code

Comment: hmm...i did a print screen of the result...is it the same as yours? [link](http://imgur.com/4JpNm)

Comment: OMG!!! THANKS Stefan!!!! I really appreciate it...never successfully fix a problem i faced yet...finally my first!!! Thank You so much!!!

Comment: You're welcome!  Glad I could help, and good luck with your projects.

Comment: Thank You so much...haha its really very tough when my groupmates are all over the place and uncontactable..Thanks...i can only rely on forums and myself to solve my many programming codes...thanks

Comment: Great - and please remember to accept my answer :) Lastly: you don't need `id='Class_1'` in the tr tag anymore. Cheers!

Comment: @Stefan is it possible to to this: `$html = "<table width='100%' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='3'>\n";` ?

Comment: Yes that is fine. Better maybe to use css, if you know how: table {width:100%;border:1px solid black;} td {padding:3px;margin:0px;}.  But your way is fine too.

Comment: sure...i will give the CSS method a try that one should be fine...Thanks so much

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9566/discussion-between-hubert-and-stefan)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the row in which you click the link, to be populated with the data from the database, do something like this (untested, but here is the gist):

HTML:

```
<tr id='class_1'>
    <td><a href='#' class='classlink' title='1'>Class 1</a></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $('a.classlink').click(function() {
        var class_id = $(this).attr('title');
        $.post("loadergetclassinfo.php", {class_id: class_id}, function(result){
            $('#class_' + class_id).html(result);
        });
    });
});
```

loadergetclassinfo.php:

```
<?php
    $class_id = empty($_POST["class_id"]) ? 1 : $_POST["class_id"];
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost", "your_MySQL_username", "your_MySQL_password") or die ("Unable to connect to MySQL Server " . mysql_error()); 
    if(is_resource($con))
        $db = mysql_select_db("your_MySQL_database", $con) or die( "Unable to select database " . mysql_error());
    $query = "SELECT data1, data2, data3 FROM your_data_table WHERE class=" . $class_id;
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    $arr_data = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    mysql_close($con);

    $html = "<td><a href='#' class='classlink' title='$class_id'>Class $class_id</a></td>";
    foreach ($arr_data as $data)
        $html .= "<td>" . $data . "</td>\n";

    echo $html;
?>
```

UPDATE:

If you want the 'Class x' data to appear somewhere else in your HTML page, you can maybe do something like this:

Add this to your HTML:

```
<div id='class_data'></div>
```

Change above jQuery like this:

```
$.post("loadergetclassinfo.php", {class: class_id}, function(result){
    $('#class_data').html(result);
});
```

Change above php code to something like this (or you can use a list or whatever you like to see here):

```
$html = "<table>\n";
$html .= "<tr><th>Class Number</th><th>Data 1</th><th>Data 2</th><th>Data 3</th></tr>\n";
$html .= "<tr><td>" . $class_id . "</td><td>" . $data['data1'] . "</td><td>" . $data['data2'] . "</td><td>" . $data['data3'] . "</td></tr>\n";
$html .= "</table>\n";

echo $html;
```

This is assuming that you have columns called `data1` etc and that your primary index is called 'class'.  Just change it to what it is in your case.

UPDATE in RESPONSE TO YOUR EDITS:

End your HTML code with:

```
<div id='detailtable'></div>
```

Edit this jQuery statement:

```
$.post("loadergetclassinfo.php", {class: class_id}, function(result){
    $('#detailtable').html(result);
});
```

Finally, remove the php code from below your HTML table, and put it in it's own file called "loadergetclassinfo.php" in the same directory as the HTML file.

ALSO, this is wrong (sorry, error was in my code):

```
$class_id = empty($_POST["class_id"]) ? 1 : $_POST["class"];
```

Should be:

```
$class_id = empty($_POST["class_id"]) ? 1 : $_POST["class_id"];
```

Also change the details table code to:

```
$html = "<table>\n";
$html .= "<tr><th>Type ID</th><th>Permit Type</th><th>Categories</th><th>Pre-    Requisisite</th><th>Description</th></tr>\n";
$html .= "<tr><td>" . $class_id . "</td><td>" . $data['PTYPE'] . "</td><td>" .     $data['TYPE'] . "</td><td>" . $data['PREREQ'] . "</td><td>" . $data['DES'] . "</td></tr>\n";
$html .= "</table>\n";
```

Comment: thanks for help...hmm but u were meaning when clicked the information will populate a new table or will populate the current table? Thanks again for help

Comment: @Hubert: I meant, the current table - because the 'Class 1' row is empty at the moment.  But you can choose any particular element's id in the jQuery result callback function, to update that element with whatever html you pass from the php script.

Comment: hmm...sorry because i don't quite understand jquery code...if i want it to come out a new table bottome...how do i go about editing the code?

Comment: Sorry for this noob question...But how do i add a jquery in a php file??? do i need to use any tag like the `</script>` ?

Comment: @Hubert: See my update. Re jQuery: Yes, just add the jQuery code inside `<script></script>` tags in the html page head, or in an external script, just like normal javascript code.  You also need to link to a copy of the jQuery library: `<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js'></script>`

Comment: @Hubert: I have changed the code in my php script so that a table is returned with the data.

Comment: @Stefen hi stefen...i have a database.php file to connect to the database...i was wondering if i can replace `$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "your_MySQL_username", "your_MySQL_password") or die ("Unable to connect to MySQL Server " . mysql_error()); 
    if(is_resource($con))
        $db = mysql_select_db("your_MySQL_database", $con) or die( "Unable to select database " . mysql_error());` with `include 'Connections/database.php';`?

Comment: Hi stefan...i am getting invalid argument error for `foreach ($arr_data as $data)`. Is there anyway i can find out what is the problem?

Comment: @Hubert: Check that you use the correct table name, primary key and column names for your data in the SELECT query - and also in the php array code in the script.

Comment: hmm...it kinda of work but the detail that was retrieve  out from the database is wrong... i Know i am 90% there...but the other 10% i cant hunt for it

Comment: @Hubert: You realize that the `title` attribute of the link is used to store the value of your primary key...? This is retrieved as $class_id into your script.  Anyway, good luck!

Comment: do you mind helping me seee whats wrong with my code?? i realise that too...i realise that he result starts from 0 therefore i change it to 1...thank you so much... wasted so much of your time

Comment: @Hubert: No problem. Update your question with your new code, as well as your table schema, and we can take a look.

Comment: After the edit...i tried cliking on the link...nothing came out

Comment: so sorry stefan...i am not sure why the clicking part is not working already...is ther e a problem with my jquery?

Comment: @Hubert: Did you change `$('#detail_table')` to `$('#detailtable')`, and `$('a.class_link')` to `$('a.classlink')`?

Comment: Yup after changing...the table still won't appear...should i put j query in the staff header instead of on another .js file?

Comment: @Hubert: I am adding comments below your original post, the comment section is getting very long here and you cannot yet chat, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

you can  try to use ajax function from jquery it could be somethink like this again you could modify it.

```
 <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
            <td>Road Based</td>
            <td>Proving Ground PG</td>
            <td>Off Road OR</td>
            <td>Towing TT</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td onclick="getPage(this)" >Class 1</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>



        <div id='content'></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function getPage(class) {
            //generate the parameter for the php script
            var data = 'page=' + document.location.hash.replace(/^.*#/, '');
            $.ajax({
                url: "loadergetclassinfo.php", 
                type: "GET",       
                data: (class).innerText,    
                cache: false,
                success: function (html) { 
                    //add the content retrieved from ajax and put it in the #content div
                    $('#content').html(html);  
                    //display the body with fadeIn transition
                    $('#content').fadeIn('slow');      
                }      
            });
        }
</script>
```