# How to display json array as repeating region from query

Tags: javascript, html, json

Currently all working with my jquery $.post actions, successful connections, query and json_encode return to my page.  What I'm unable to do(and new to json) is how to display the returned values as a live feed?  My current jquery js file is 'jquery-1.7.2.min.js' and my code is

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      setInterval(function(){
      $.post('query.php', function(pendingReq){
      $('#div_id').html(pendingReq);
      }), 'json' });
    }, 5000

);
```

pendingReq is my returned data from the query and the current output looks like:
`{"[0]":"FirstReq", "[1]":"SecondReq", ...."}` based upon my mysql query build of the array

```
$res = array("[0]"=>var['1']...);
```

I am very new to using json, and don't use a lot of javascript, but would like to have the returned data show up in a table, thank you.

My code below works, but for only one row of the mysql query, if two entries exist I get a "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {" error in Firebug??  Still returning results as before:

```
    $res = array("req_name"=>$ew_display['req_name'], "date"=>$ew_display['req_dt']);
echo json_encode($res);



$(document).ready(function(){
            var table_template = "<table border=1 cellspacing=0 id='results'><tr><th>JTAR #</th><th>JTAR @</th></tr></table>";
            $("#testd").html(table_template);
    setInterval(function(){
        $.post("query.php", {track : 2}, function(pendingReq){
            var json = JSON.parse(pendingReq);
            var template = "<tr><td>{{req_name}}</td><td>{{date}}</td></tr>";
            var new_row = Mustache.render(template, json); 
            $("#results").append(new_row).fadeIn("slow");
        }), "json"
}, 5000);
```

Comment: @dbaseman any ideas?  The first problem was my jquery statement, it was wrong, now I'm guessing this is caused by the array in the callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-- EDIT --

Since you've got an interval in there, the template can be constant:

```
var table_template = "<table border=1 cellspacing=0 id='results_table'><tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th></tr></table>";
$("#div_id").html(table_template);
var template = "<tr><td>{{[0]}}</td><td>{{[1]}}</td></tr>";
```

Now for the interval, you can parse the result string and render each row:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.post("query.php", function(pendingReq) {
        var json = JSON.parse(pendingReq);
        var new_row = Mustache.render(template, json); 
        $("#results_table").append(new_row);
    });
});
```

-- END EDIT --

I'm a big fan of Mustache.js (https://github.com/janl/mustache.js), which allows you to separate your data (JSON) from your presentation (HTML table).  I'm not a big fan of returning AJAX data from your server pre-formatted as HTML.  You can use syntax like this (example only):

```
var template = "<table>{{#item}}<tr><td>{{name}}</td><td>{{age}}</td><td>{{job}}</td></tr>{{/item}}</table>";
var html = Mustache.render(template, pendingReq);
$('#div_id').html(html);
```

Comment: Didn't know about this!  Anyway, if you don't have Mustache, returning html directly is better than struggling to display the json via javascript, IMHO.

Comment: Downloaded mustache, made an include on my page and used the above example and replaced name, age, job with my variables, and just a blank page(also built my own div_id).  I have put the above example code as part of my function 'code'                                                                  $(document).ready(function(){
 setInterval(function(){
  $.post("earf1.php", function(pendingReq){
   var template = "<table><tr><td>{{req_name}}</td><td>{{date}}</td></tr></table>";
   
   var html = Mustache.render(template, pendingReq);
   $('#ew').html(html);
   }),
 "json" });
}, 5000);'code'

Comment: @dbaseman Still struggling to fully understand the mustache way, and I believe it's that my query return is a string not an object, as it shows {"0":"val1", "1":"val2"...}, would this be correct?

Comment: @ChadW we need to find out if it's a string or an object.  If it's a string, you should be able to do $("#ew").html(JSON.parse(pendingReq)["0"] and see "val1".  If it's an object, $("#ew").html(pendingReq["0"]) should give you "val1".

Comment: @dbaseman I want to thank you, as much as I'd like to use the mustache, something I'm doing is wrong, guessing my script include mustache.js is not right?  I think it would be awesome to use

Comment: @ChadW are you familiar with Firebug at all?  It's built-in to Chrome and a plug-in for Firefox.  Hugely helpful for debugging Javascript.  Anyways, you can always test if Mustache loaded by adding something like this to your script: if (!window.Mustache) alert("couldn't load mustache");

Answer (score 0):

Chad , please use json_encode() for your array "$res"

```
echo json_encode($res);
```

If php returns a string, then you can use

```
var json = JSON.parse(pendingReq);
```

Once you get the json object , you can use the . operator to access the properties.

First find out what your json contains...
do:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(json));
```

stringify converts a json object to readable string
you can convert back using JSON.parse;
You can access the properties by doing json.property.

Now you can have a table which keeps updating all the data.
Consider an object like this:
var obj = {name:"Adam",age:35,job:"Programmer"};
You can add this information to the table by:

```
$("#table").html($("#table").html() + "<tr><td>" + obj.name + "</td><td>" + obj.age + "</td><td>" + obj.job + "</td></tr>");
```

Comment: When I comment out var json = JSON.parse(pendingReq); and use alert(JSON.stringify(pendingReq)); I do see the text appear in the alert window, however when I try the above with the var = json, I have a blank screen?

Comment: Tried one more thing, deleted 2 of my 3 tables from sql, and the output worked, and kept looping endlessly the same output, so my question now is, how do I stop the display once the loop query has stopped?  And how do I cycle the json code to the next array?  Thank you for the above also

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery documentation shows how you can use json which is returned, inside the ajax callback function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

But instead of returning your query results as json, why don't you return html (table code containing your results) and then directly display that html inside a div?

Here is an example of doing something like that:
[Modifying the AJAX PHP database example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966612/modifying-the-ajax-php-database-example/9966992#9966992)

UPDATE: How to return data as html instead of json:

OK, let's say your php script currently returns a json encoded string:

```
$str_json = '{"0":"FirstReq", "1":"SecondReq", ...."}';
```

Now do something like this in the php script - depending on what you want to show of course:

```
$lst_data = json_decode($str_json);

$html = "<table>\n<tr>\n";
foreach ($lst_data as $i => $data) {
    $html .= "<th>" . $i . "</th>";
$html .= "</tr>\n<tr>\n";
foreach ($lst_data as $data) {
    $html .= "<td>" . $data . "</td>";
}
$html .= "</tr>\n</table>\n";

echo $html;
```

EDIT:  You probably have something similar to this:

```
$res = mysql_fetch_assoc($data);

// Remove this from your script:  echo json_encode($res);

// Add this:
$html = "<table>\n<tr>\n";
foreach ($res as $i => $r) {
    $html .= "<th>" . $i . "</th>";
$html .= "</tr>\n<tr>\n";
foreach ($res as $r) {
    $html .= "<td>" . $r . "</td>";
}
$html .= "</tr>\n</table>\n";

echo $html;
```

...and remember to set dataType in jQuery $.post() function to `html`.

Comment: How would I return it as html from my sql query? htmlentities?

Comment: Just create an html string containing normal html code which you want to see, and echo this at the end of the script: `$html = '<table>...(use php data from query)..</table>'; echo $html;`

Comment: Also change dataType parameter in .post() function to 'html' (or leave it blank).

Comment: So I don't understand where the $lst_data = json_decode($str_json) came from.  My php returns the array {"0":"FirstReq"....} from an echo json_encode($res) from my sql query on a seperate page?

Comment: @Chad W: $str_json = json_encode($res);  So it looks like `$res = $lst_data`.  In which case you can remove the json_encode and json_decode statements in your script and make sure that $lst_data in my code is the same as $res in your code.

Comment: thank you for the update, it works wonderfully.  I'm also curious as to the mustache response, I can't seem to understand that one?

Comment: @Chad W: Haven't used Mustache myself.  Have you read the readme? https://github.com/janl/mustache.js#readme.  In the code in your comment to dbaseman - I'm guessing you should use a `{{#pendingReq}}` mustached variable just after `<table>`.